# How to insert one item before the first item currently without xpath in Domdocument using PHP

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

e.g

```
<p>
    <span>item1</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span>item2</span>
</p>
```

I want to insert a new item, `<p><span>item0</span></p>`, before "item1", but I don't know how.
I googled that there is a method named `insertBefore`, but after looking at the examples, it seems I need XPath.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code to learn how to format code in questions and answers.

Comment: In what form do you have the HTML fragment in hand?

Comment: XPath has nothing to do with `insertBefore`. Most likely XPath was only used to get a reference to the node you want to call `insertBefore` on.

Comment: Thanks for correcting format and the url.